# Glare alpha not saved to png file

Tags: transparency, glare

I'm using the "glare" node in the compositing view, with a transparent background. The results in the blender image viewer look fine: (notice the blueish glare around the monkey, over a transparent background)

[image]

However, after using "Image > save", the blue glare is gone, it seems like the alpha of the original image is used, no matter what settings I change.

[image]

Using blender 3.1.2. [Test file here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rlTML9ylWTLTBmpyfli57XakxFsDgda4/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: You can't export PNG with the bloom or compositor effects and transparency, I've read that it was possible with EXR format but I couldn't make it work, perhaps someone will tell. That said there are some tricks that you can use: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tmb5HRU1cUo

Comment: @moonboots is spot on with the youtube link, skip to around 11:40 for the answer. The info before should almost be required to watch for anyone learning compositing though! For what it's worth, this isn't just a blender problem and you'll run into this in many other compositing programs. It's how a glare/glow effect is created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is possible after all using `color to alpha` function in [the gimp](https://www.gimp.org/). Not 100% physically accurate maybe, but the effect looks great, and has simple transparency, allowing you to layer the image over different backgrounds.

Render your image twice:

[image]

Once with a black background and glare:

[image]

Once with transparent background (but no glare of course)

[image]

Now in **the gimp**, first load the black background image, select `Colors` > `Color to alpha` and select pure black as the color to make alpha.

Now put the transparent background image in a layer on top to "fill in" any parts that became transparent but shouldn't.

There you go, great looking glare with true transparency.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Thanks @moonboots for posting [that video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tmb5HRU1cUo). After watching it I understood that "glare" or "bloom" is **physically impossible** to render correctly with an opacity layer. In simple terms, the blend mode for the glare must be `add` (sometimes called `lighten`), and it simply cannot be emulated using transparency without looking wrong in many cases. A way to think about this is that a nice glare depends on the background, and since it isn't known in advance it cannot be rendered using opacity only.

Knowing that, it's actually quite simple to separate out just the "outside" glare to a separate image in Blender, so that you can simply use it with `lighten`/`add` blend mode in the program of your choice:

[image]

Use the following compositing nodes to get the glare layer:

[image]