How can I have bloom and transparency on my animation?
I am making a transparent animation with EEVEE bloom. How can I make this work? I have tried some tutorials but they don’t work. When i try to use them it looks fine in blender but when it’s saved, it only has the bloom without the actual object so it is just white and bloom. How could I fix this?

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57816/how-do-i-get-the-glare-node-to-output-transparent-instead-of-black-background https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/173932/exr-color-difference-to-png https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/260675/glare-alpha-not-saved-to-png-file https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/222837/blender-does-not-set-the-alpha-channel-correctly/222893#222893
