Transparent PNGs not exporting properly
I have my render settings set to PNG (RBGA) with transparancy checked under film. My compositor setup is a simple denoise and glare node.
When I render, the result is as expected. The glare looks alright as you can see below:

But after exporting, the glow around the mesh isn't preserved in the final image. It's as if it's being clipped to the shape of the mesh and no glow goes beyond that point:

I've also tried using Open EXR hoping that would preserve all data, but that didn't help also.
So could someone help me out with this? Thanks

the glow effects won't be preserved on transparent PNG, you can't fix it except with some tricks with layers in the Compositor or in your video editor

What do you mean, OpenEXR did not help? It depends on where you open it and how it is processed. If you save it as EXR in Blender and import the image back into Blender, then given you use the same Color Management settings etc. you'll get the correct result. But that does not mean that other software will process it the exact same way and give you the same result.

Thanks for the detailed answer @josh sanfelici, really helpful. I'll consider investing more time to learn how Open EXR works. Gordon, yeah, I just imported the EXR into premiere pro to see if the glow effect would still be there, and it wasn't. I didn't try any other methods. But thank you. I now have a better understanding of how it works.

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/260675/glare-alpha-not-saved-to-png-file https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/222837/blender-does-not-set-the-alpha-channel-correctly https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/272917/transparent-emissive-objects-glow-effect-not-visible-in-rendered-output-files/272919#272919 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/173932/exr-color-difference-to-png

This is an old question, that has been asked many times, I'm answering only to showcase one solution that can be useful for many users.
First of all the problem doesn't rely on Blender but on PNG format itself, because it handles Unassociated alpha only: it means that when a PNG is read from any application, its color values get multiplied with its alpha values: alpha of glowing pixels is zero or nearly zero, so glow colors become zero or nearly zero.
EXR format handles Associated alpha, so it can carry pixels that are both glowing and transparent, and this is the professional standard, widely used for compositing CG transparent footage or images, but it adds some complexity to the workflow because it has to be correctely color managed, as its stored values are Scene referred with linear Gamma, which is not straightforward to handle, depending on the compositor software.
I encourage everyone to learn how to correctly handle EXR and color management, but here's a trick to use PNG for transparent glowing images (or even image sequences):
Save your render as PNG RGB, so that the background will be black.
Add a new material and delete its shader, leaving the material output unconnected, call it PitchBlack.
Switch to Cycles (if you were on Eevee), go to Scene properties > Override, and set this new material as Material override.
Turn down to 1 max Samples Render option and launch another Render (very fast), save it as PNG RGBA, so to have an image which has transparent background and black objects.

Now in compositor (Photoshop, DaVinci, After Effect, .....) add this Black/transparent layer with Normal fusion method, then add the RGB layer with fusion method set to ADD or LINEAR DODGE (depending on the software).


You cannot composite all lighting effects using alpha mask only
Alpha masks determine visibility of something over something else. This means that if you have 0.5 in alpha, there will be half of the image below visible and half of the image above visible in the result. The pixel values are "mixed". The more you see of one of the images, the less you can see the other. This is not what happens with most things that emit light. With emitted light the whole image is still visible, but it gets brighter - pixel values are added on top of the previous image. This is true for visible light sources and various light effects like glow, lens flares, even light effects that you see because of fog or mist scattering light back to the camera, flame, explosions and so on. You simply cannot use only alpha for compositing those, because they are not supposed to be mixed with the image, but added.
I tried to come up with an example, but I realized, I really have no idea, how to render any glow or light effects masked with alpha(same problem as you are facing :D), because well... it's not really done like that and makes no sense. So to make it a bit clearer and to show how it works, even though this is not something you would need to do as part of compositing usually let's say I have 3 images. They are all rendered to 32bit EXR so they are in linear color space and all data is preserved so I can use them for compositing(unlike say 8bit PNGs in non linear sRGB color space). First has 2 monkeys and a cube, second has same 2 monkeys and the cube is glowing, and the third one has the monkeys in different colors and the cube doesn't glow:

The glow and light of the cube in the second image is the difference between the first two images and you can see that if I simply subtract the image without light from the image with light, I am left with the light information:

Now I can add only that light to the other image with different colored monkeys:

So this hopefully demonstrates how light is added to an image and you don't use alpha for this, you just need to have whatever light effect you want to composite alone on black background and then use add operation for it to work correctly.

If you do everything in Blender and created the glow most likely with a Glare node in Blender as well, it would make much more sense to render the image without glow and the output of the Glare node separately and then add the glow on top of the image, instead of rendering the image twice and subtracting one from the other. What your example doesn't show is the color bleed either when using it to relight a different render than the original, it's more obvious with more different colors: color bleed. The monkeys get colored, the floor as well...

Just an illustration to have something visual. The point is alpha is for transparency, glow is not transparency no matter my poor method of coming up with whatever light effect I could composite.
