Fire with transparency shown in render but when saved as PNG or OpenEXR is different
I have tried this thread. I couldn't find any other threads on BSE about this problem. The fire with transparency doesn't work. I mean I can see it in the output:

But when saving (Image > Save As) as PNG or OpenEXR or TIFF or any other format it always gets clipped on areas where just the emissive flame is visible with no background:

When importing EXR into Blender I get:

The aforementioned thread claims to use EXR as solution but it still gets clipped when importing into Blender. The colors are even worse. What is the workaround to this? I don't want to save with black background.
UPDATE: The duplicated thread is not correct as it was not Blender specific solution. The correct answer is explained pixel perfect solution here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tmb5HRU1cUo

The thread you linked is the correct answer, and saving as OpenEXR should work. When you say it doesn’t, what software are you viewing this EXR with and what are you trying to do with it? It’s possible the software you’re taking the EXR to is not handling the alpha channel properly

@JtheNinja I imported the EXR back into Blender 4.3 because I want to render the EXR image sequence on top of another video clip so it needs to be transparent but still same issue of clipping, and the colors are even worse.

Exr should work, so you could upload the file, to see what went wrong. Here is a possible workaround: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/328027/transparent-pngs-not-exporting-properly/328033#328033

@joshsanfelici no EXR will not work. The correct answer is explained here: :) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tmb5HRU1cUo He also experienced the same thing as me that EXR does not work.

@MeganLove I agree that simply drag and drop the Exr doesn't work, but exr contains all data needed to correctly compose the glare + transparency effect, and it's the standard professional, widely used, because it carries all data into a single file (even when using single layer format), and it stores scene color in a linear fashion, which is better for color grading, but it has to be correctly handled.

I know the topic is complex, and there are many misleading answers (like the one linked as duplicate), but if you see the link I proposed, you will notice that it's matematically identical to the YouTube video you linked. Going to exr is a step further because of single file and Linear Colors workflow.

@joshsanfelici Thank you for clarifying this I will dig deeper then :)

BTW, if you drag and drop an exr into Blender compositor and use alpha over node, it works right out of the box (not the case in VSE).
